# gif動画の再生回数「１回」について

Tags: python, pillow

Python, Pillowを使ってGIFを作っています。再生すると往復しますが、そういうもんなのでしょうか？
例えば、ある図形を画面の左から右へ片道（１回）動いて終わる動画を作ったつもりなのですが、再生すると、左から右へ行った後、右から左へ戻ってきて再生が終了します。

引数loopは未設定（デフォルト）です。

---

回答、コメントをくださった皆さん、ありがとうございます。

実は、もともとは
https://note.nkmk.me/python-opencv-mosaic/
徐々にモザイクがかかるGIFアニメ作成
から持ってきていて、

```
imgs += imgs[-2::-1] + [Image.fromarray(src)] * 5

imgs[0].save('data/temp/opencv_mosaic.gif',
             save_all=True, append_images=imgs[1:], optimize=False, duration=50)
```

という感じになっています

Comment: 説明を読む限り、ループとはまた違う動作に見えます。実際のコードを質問に追加するか、引数 loop を明示的に `1` にした場合を試すなどしてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: [Image file formats - GIF - Saving](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving) の `loop` パラメータの説明には "Integer number of times the GIF should loop. 0 means that it will loop forever. **By default, the image will not loop**." と書かれています。実際、手元の環境で試してみると `loop` パラメータを指定しない場合はループ再生しません。

Comment: `imgs += imgs[-2::-1] + ...` の `imgs[-2::-1]` の部分は `imgs`(画像オブジェクトのリスト)の「反転」を意味しています。つまり、「左から右へ行った後、右から左へ戻ってきて…」は正しく動作している事になります。

Comment: 解説ありがとうございます。
[-2::-1]　はどの部分が「反転」の意味なのでしょうか？[]の中全部ですか？

Comment: @BrainOverflow はい、そうです。例えば、`lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` として、`lst += lst[-2::-1]` を実行後に `lst` の内容を確認してみて下さい。

Answer (score 0):

gif 画像におけるループはあくまで同じ動きのループであり、逆再生は行われません。したがって gif 画像を作成しているプログラム側のバグが疑われるので、そちらを調査してみてください。